# How to design a form that requires the user fill in one text field out of three

Tags: website-design, forms, multi-selection, options

I am having a form where I want the user to fill in one text field out of 3. These 3 fields are used to identify other clients in different ways (Phone number, Email or Name). The last text field is a autocomplete field.

Of course this form has other fields to be filled in. I am wondering what is the best and most intuitive way to make the user understand that he/she is only demanded to fill in one of those options and others will be neglected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Could you combine all 3 in a singe field with the label "Phone Number, Email or Name". Other than that I can only suggest using text to describe what the user should do - "Please fill in **ONE** of the following:" for example.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxOYhA.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: That's a really cool idea (number, mail or name). Makes it harder to validate and process by the system, but a very pleasing way of interacting with the user! Hope it's not completely different from what wael needs :)

Comment: Yeah I agree with Alexej. It would be tough for validation and autocomplete feature.

Comment: Do you think? I don't think so - a simple regex and case statement - could be done purely client side, server side or ajax combination of both

Comment: yeah you are right. But how would I handle autocomplete? for example someone could start with "test" that could be start of an email (which should not be autocompleted) or a name which should be autocompleted. My point is how would I know when to autocomolete or not.

Comment: @wael34218 - I don't really think that matters. When the user is typing an email address, he'll pretty soon reach a point (e.g. when typing '.' or '@') where autocomplete doesn't return suggestions.

Comment: Would people with an @ in their name mess up the validation?

Comment: Why would you autocomplete a field like that to begin with?

Comment: I did wonder that too. Auto-detecting the format is one thing, autocomplete for a field like this seems very odd!

Comment: While I love the simplicity of the second option, the programmer in me dreads dealing with it.

Comment: Agree completely. Having come from a dev background and now being a UXer I sometimes feel VERY guilty when I tell the devs how I need things to work. It rarely lasts.

Comment: If it has an @ it's an email address. If it has any numbers and not an @ it's a phone number. Anything else is a name. That figures out what it is quickly then you can validate further from there.

Answer (score 9):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuWUij.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If you can have one and only one identification method, then let them select which they want to use via a group of 3 radio buttons and once they select one make the label and input for that identification method visible or have them disabled until selected via a radio button.

The advantage of having the radios with separate inputs over just putting "Name, Email or Phone Number" on  label is that you know what you are validating and you can give each input a standard id so that they have appropriate autocomplete behaviour. See these Q&As:

- [Form field names used by personal data auto-fill in browsers (Safari, Opera)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027462/form-field-names-used-by-personal-data-auto-fill-in-browsers-safari-opera)
- [Which Attributes Does Chrome Autofill Expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268338/which-attributes-does-chrome-autofill-expect)

Comment: It is currently implemented this way. But I think there should be more intuitive way.

Comment: Would be interesting to see this approach in a usability study. I could imagine some would try to fill out every form field buy clicking on the first radio, typing in, then the next radio, typing in again an so on. And if the text would disappear after changing the radios, they would say "why did it disappear?"

Comment: @wael34218, you could always arrange the radios horizontally and have one textbox which makes it clear you only want one value.

Comment: @AlexejFroehlich it shouldn't forget values. Even with the single input you could have it switch the inputs so if you changed your mind and then went back to the previous choice it would bring back what you'd previously entered.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a **automatic verification of the entered input** to check if its a name (characters), email (at-sign) or phone number (numbers). This way you would need only one input field for this three. After validation it would be good style to highlight the recognized input - if a user entered numbers, you would highlight phone number.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have the required field marked in a way that it stands out of the rest of the controls. Convention on the web often shows a star (*) but other required field options are available. Some uses a light yellow color to highlight the required field(s).

Also right-align the labels to every field, making it easier for the user to read which field is connected to which label.

Use a Submit-button, and a Cancel-button, even if the cancal button isn't really necessary.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHnUSX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If one out of three is required, have the submit-button disabled until the user fills at least one field with text - and use an explanatory text to highlight what is required.

If there are more fields (as you say), gruop the three fields together in a container, making it easier for the user to find out which fields are in question.

Comment: I'd put the text note above or to the left of the fields to increase the likelyhood the user will read it. I'd also make it as short as possible. "One of"